# How to regenerate configure file using autoconf?

Tags: r, configure, autoconf

I use autoconf to regenerate the configure file, it works. But when I execute the generated configure file by `./configure`, there are some error messages like

```
./configure: line 3713: syntax error near unexpected token `blas'
./configure: line 3713: `  withval=$with_blas; R_ARG_USE(blas)'
```

I googled and found that `blas` is a library, but it still gives the error messages after installing. I have the autoconf with version "`autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.69`" installed on my Mac, and what I am trying to compile is the R source `https://svn.r-project.org/R/`.

---

I have run both autoconf -f and autoreconf -f to try to regenerate configure file which has been generated successfully. But, when I run `./configure` the error happens again.

The error messages say `syntax error near unexpected token blas` and `withval=$with_blas; R_ARG_USE(blas)`. I think the problem maybe the unknown function `R_ARG_USE`. I grep `R_ARG_USE` in the code base and find that it is defined in the file m4/R.m4:

```
AC_DEFUN([R_ARG_USE],
[if test "${withval}" = no; then
  use_$1=no
else
  use_$1=yes
fi
])# R_ARG_USE
```

Does that mean when I am running autoconf or autoreconf I miss something to let it know the existence of m4/R.m4 ?

I have been stuck here for almost three days, any helps will be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try it like this `AC_ARG_WITH([blas],
[AS_HELP_STRING([--with-blas],[use system BLAS library (if available), or specify it @<:@no@:>@])],
[R_ARG_USE(blas)],
[use_blas=unset])`  and make sure you actually have it installed of course

Comment: @Hack-R Thanks for reply! But why there is syntax error in configure file which is generated by autoconf automatically? I mean, if the configure.ac is correct (which is the file in the R svn), why does the configure generated by the correct configure.ac have syntax error ?

Comment: Try to run 'autoreconf -f -i'. This forces to regenerate all the files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems I have solved this problem. I reinstall the gnu m4 using `brew install m4` and the problem solved.
After running `autoreconf -i -f`, I can get the correct configure file and the R source can be compiled.
Maybe it's the wrong version m4 I have got in Mac.

Comment: I actually had to do `brew install homebrew/dupes/m4 && brew install libtool` and then `autoreconf -i -f -I m4` on OSX 10.11.6 and R 3.3.1