# How do I run the ./configure script on git package?

Tags: linux, autotools, autoconf, gnash

I am trying to install gnash on debian. I did (as root):

```
git clone git://git.sv.gnu.org/gnash.git
cd gnash/
./configure
```

And got:

```
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Git and nothing direct to do with Linux: the repository (I cloned it to see) comes without the `configure` file. It has instead `configure.ac`, which is an autoconf input file. For instructions on using it, see the separate `README.git` file, which tells you what else you need install first (if you haven't yet) and then run in order to build the `./configure` file that you use to build gnash. (I'll delete the [tag:git] tag but I'm not sure what tags are actually appropriate for this question.)

Comment: Aha: the tag is [tag:gnash] (of course!)

Comment: This was helpful. Thank you @torek.

Comment: @gatorreina Any particular reason you're not just installing it from the repos?

Comment: Did you try 'file configure'? If the file exists, check '+x' attribute.

Comment: yes because apt-get install gnash resulted in E: Package 'gnash' has no installation candidate

Comment: @gatorreina Well, [it’s definitely there](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=all&suite=all&section=all&keywords=gnash). It’s probably a better idea to get it working through the repos (an `apt update` might be enough to fix it).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to regenerate configure file using autoconf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37717356/how-to-regenerate-configure-file-using-autoconf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gnash :

```
apt-get install g++ autoconf libtool libgconf2-dev libjemalloc-dev libgif-dev libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev libspeex-dev  libspeexdsp-dev libagg-dev xulrunner-dev libming-dev libming-util mtasc haxe swfmill libcsound64-dev dejagnu
```

> git clone git://git.sv.gnu.org/gnash.git

```
cd gnash/
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
```